# To which screen window belongs?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, quartz-graphics

I'am using CGWindowListOption and CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo to find windows list on multiple screens (I have additional display):

```
let options = CGWindowListOption(arrayLiteral: CGWindowListOption.OptionOnScreenOnly, CGWindowListOption.ExcludeDesktopElements)
let windows = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(options, CGWindowID(0))! as NSArray
...
for window in windows {
    ...
    var bounds: CGRect = CGRect()
    CGRectMakeWithDictionaryRepresentation(window["kCGWindowBounds"] as! CFDictionary, &bounds)
    ...
}
```

window variable is a dictionary - it is not NSWindow object (so I can't get screen property). 
How do I found out on which of my screens window is located? Can I do it somehow using window coordinates?

Comment: Bear in mind that the window may straddle two (or more) screens.